# How to handle synchronization fast concurrent read/writes in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, list, concurrency, data-synchronization

I am trying to set up an analysis tool in android. I have several **Listener** which are fetching some signal data (float values) every 10 ms. Each signal is supposed to be stored in its own **List**.
Based on all the signal values we get in each 10ms steps, I need to compute a state based on some restrictions and store it in a **List** as well.

It is not unlikely that the analysis runs for like 2h, therefore the **List** can get quite big (**~600.000** entries for 100 minutes for each signal). All the **Lists** are currently wrapped in a **RootList**, like **`List<List<float>>`**.

So I got a lot of write operations which only runs in one thread and a lot of read operations which are running from other threads (computing the states and doing some graphical representation). All this should be done in real-time and not after the analysis is done.

Since I need to do write and read operations concurrently, I thought about which implementation I could use to maintain the real-time computation aspect.

## **ReadWriteLock**

I am not too sure if **ReadWriteLocks** are sufficient for my case, since my computation needs to happen as soon as all values are available and if I add values each 10ms in every **List** I would guess that it is basically locked the whole time?!

## **CopyOnWriteArrayList**

I don't think **CopyOnWriteArrayList** fits my need either because i got a lot of write operations and I will be copying the **Arrays** endlessly. But I might be wrong here, maybe someone with more expertise can comment on that.

---

Maybe I could use the **Collections.synchronizedList()** or some other predefined synchronized implementations. But since I am writing/reading the values in such a frequent time interval it might not be the best idea either.

Are there any other clever ways to achieve what I want or is something I wrote valuable and only I see the problems? Maybe there even is a recommended way of doing this? Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `BlockingQueue` (assuming you want to process the contents in a FIFO fashion).

Comment: @AndyTurner If I read it correctly, you need to initialize the `BlockingQueue` with a fixed size (at least I found no constructors without it). But at the start of the measurement I don't know how it is going to be. And even if I knew, is is the lock/unlock mechanism fast enough to keep up? But regardless, thx for your input

Comment: But if you are writting from a single thread then having a lock-free regular list or array will work (provided it is volatile or final). You don't need to lock for reading, and makes no sense to lock if only one thread mutates the list.